# How many matches can you fit?

Tags: matches

I have a board with some matches on it, in the shape of a number.

By adding one match, you make a larger number appear than before.

By adding a second match, you make it smaller.

By adding a third match, you make it bigger again.

And with a fourth match, you get something the same as I started with. What is the largest amount of matches I could have started with? Prove your concept and how to add the extra matches.

*Additional rules:*

> Once a match is placed, it is stuck on the board in that position. The starting configuration may be determined by you as necessary to complete the puzzle.
>
> Matches must be in identifiably different positions. Overlaid matches will not count.
>
> "Smaller" means magnitude. -1 is the same size as +1. -3 is larger than +2.
>
> The board does not allow matches to pass through it.
>
> All matches must be undamaged.
>
> Numerals must be Arabic, seven-segment, or Roman. Votes will serve as judgement of what is close enough to recognise as a number.

Comment: Do you at least have one solution in mind here?

Comment: I had a couple, but they are (apparently very) suboptimal. Wanted to see what else others could come up with.

Comment: Why the hold-putting? There's clearly one correct answer. The fact it can be and has been shown in several ways doesn't give it multiplicity. Nor are good answers to the puzzle long at all: the best is only a few lines. There are puzzles requiring far more explanation and which haven't been definitively answered, that remain open. Others have explicitly open-ended possibilities and likewise. Why is this obviously precise and concisely-solved puzzle considered broader or necessarily longer to respond to?

Comment: @f'' JonMarkPerry, CodeNewbie, Deusovi, EngineerToast: could you respond to these concerns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution that fits the stricter criteria that numbers must be smaller or larger than all preceding numbers (in a similar fashion to my original, below):

> $(6-5)\space\space\space\space\space(6-5)=1$
>  $(8-5)\space\space\space\space\space(6-5)=3$
>  $(8-5)\space\space\space\space\space(6-6)=0$
>  $(8-5)\space\space\space\space\space(8-6)=6$
>  $(8-5)-(8-6)=1$

Again we can

> Prepend our numbers with $8888\cdots8$
>  $(8888\cdots86-8888\cdots85)\space\space\space\space\space(8888\cdots86-8888\cdots85)=1$
>  $(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots85)\space\space\space\space\space(8888\cdots86-8888\cdots85) = 3$
>  $(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots85)\space\space\space\space\space(8888\cdots86-8888\cdots86) = 0$
>  $(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots85)\space\space\space\space\space(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots86) = 6$
>  $(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots85)-(8888\cdots88-8888\cdots86) = 1$

For example:

> With two leading $8$s on each number, yellow matches are those added:
>
>  [image]

---

My first solution...

This uses

> $11$ initial matches:
>
> ```
>  _     _
> |_  _ |_
>  _|    _|
>
>  _     _
> |_  _ |_
> |_|    _|
>
>  _     _
> |_  _ |_
> |_|   |_|
>
>  _     _
> |_| _ |_
> |_|   |_|
>
>  _     _
> |_| _ |_|
> |_|   |_|
> ```

To increase the number simply

> prepend both sides of the difference with $8888\cdots8$
>
>  $8888\cdots85-8888\cdots85=0$
>  $8888\cdots86-8888\cdots85=1$
>  $8888\cdots86-8888\cdots86=0$
>  $8888\cdots88-8888\cdots86=2$
>  $8888\cdots88-8888\cdots88=0$

Alternatively

> start with $n$ matches side-by-side for each segment of the three seven segment displays originally shown

Comment: Very good, it gives me ideas for other solutions.

Comment: oops, missed last case, added it.

Comment: You can easily use large number of matchsticks; simply start with 111...15-111...15.

Comment: @Ankoganit thought that was obvious, added text to that effect

Comment: @Ankoganit and another way :)

Comment: I don't understand the last alternative; can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ankoganit - replace each match in my original example with $n$ matches side-by-side, the digits become more and more "squished" and the inserted matches are much thinner segments than the originals, but the result represent the same things.

Comment: Added a solution that adheres to the strict criteria that bigger means bigger than all preceding and smaller means smaller than all preceding.

Comment: The latest version following strictest larger/smaller conditions is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

My solution assumes

> Operators are allowed since they aren't explicitely forbidden

Solution

> matches ads high as roman numerals go, Will get an actual number tomorrow when I have more time if this method is ok. 
>  DCC..XXXI- DCC..XXXI = 0 
>  DCC..XXXII- DCC..XXXI = 1 larger 
>  DCC..XXXII- DCC..XXXII = 0 smaller 
>  DCC..XXXIII- DCC..XXXII = 1 larger 
>  DCC..XXXIII- DCC..XXXIII = 0 same as original

Or

> COULD also us arabic transforming 3s to 8s instead of adding 1s which would make it basically unlimited matchstick.

To make them larger and smaller then the original

> 8333 - 3333 = 5000 
>  8383 - 3333 = 5050 larger 
>  8383 - 3833 = 4550 smaller then original and preceding 
>  8883 - 3833 = 5050 larger then original and preceding 
>  8883 - 3883 = 5000 back to original 
>  proceed with as many match numbers as you want

Next logical tightening is

> larger or smaller then all proceeding numbers, don't have a solution for that yet

Comment: Good effort. Though it might be argued that 0 is the same as 0 still (larger/smaller than the original, not just the preceding number, would be a tighter condition).

Comment: It just says smaller which I read as smaller then the previous

Comment: Of course, and fair enough to do so. Can you get something similarly large with the stricter condition?

Answer (score 4):

We can begin with

> $2n+1$ matchsticks for any positive integer $n$.

I will describe the case $n=3.$

Begin with

> $|||-|||$ which is $111-111=0$.

Add a matchstick to get

> $||||-|||$ which is $1111-111=1000$.

Add another matchstick to get

> $-||||-|||$ which is $-1111-111=-1222.$

Another matchstick may be suitably placed to obtain

> $+||||-|||$ which is $+1111-111=1000$.

Now comes the fourth matchstick, which yields

> $+||||-||||$ which is $+1111-1111=0$.

So we get back to where we started.

If $+$ counts as overlay, then we can do the following, as suggested by Jonathan Allan:

> $|||-|||=0\to ||||-|||=1000\to ||||-||||=0\to |||||-||||=10000\to |||||-|||||=0.$

Obviously, for general $n$, we can start with

> $\underbrace{|||\cdots | |}_{n\text{ sticks}}-\underbrace{|||\cdots ||}_{n\text{ sticks}}$.

Then we procced as above.

Comment: "Overlaid matches will not count."

Comment: @JonathanAllan I interpreted it as matches which are exactly superimposed, since the preceding sentence says that the matches just have to be in identifiably different position.

Comment: To get rid of the overlaid problem with $+$, you could do $111-111=0$, $1111-111=1000$, $1111-1111=0$, $11111-1111=10000$, $11111-11111=0$

Comment: @JonathanAllan that's what I had in mind at first; but I was trying to satisfy the stricter condition which the OP mentioned in the comments to gtwebb's answer. Anyway, I'll add this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: He mentioned in the OP that it is magnitude so -1222 is actually bigger then +1000 which doesn't match the conditions